# if lines of txt file start with numbers in another txt file python

Tags: python, compare, line

```
with open('D:\Scripting Test/Full Data.txt') as f:
 for line in f:
   with open('D:\Scripting Test/Numbers.txt') as ff:
     for linee in ff:
       if line.startswith(linee):
           print(line)
```

i want to print all lines in file (full-data.txt) if they start with any numbers in file (numbers.txt)

full-data.txt:

```
4/0/0        
3/0/7        
4/0/7        
4/0/3        
4/0/4        
4/0/1        
3/0/5        
3/0/1        
2/0/5        
2/0/3        
2/0/4        
2/0/6        
3/0/2        
1/0/3        
6/0/6        
6/0/12       
1/0/5        
1/0/4        
3/0/4
```

Numbers.txt:

```
1 

2 

5 

8
```

output should be:

```
2/0/5        
2/0/3        
2/0/4        
2/0/6

1/0/3

1/0/5        
1/0/4
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include what issue you're having with this code?

Comment: Also this `D:\Scripting Test/Full Data.txt` is not valid in Python because a single backslash will cause Python to look for an escape sequence. Either use only forward slashes, put an `r` before the string to tell Python it's a raw string, or use double back slashes

Comment: the issue that i couldn't print my desire output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that when you read in some of the numbers, they include whitespace like newline characters and spaces. So try first reading in all of the numbers into an array and stripping any whitespace away:

```
nums = []
with open('D:\\Scripting Test\\Numbers.txt') as f:
    nums = f.read().split('\n')
    nums = [n.strip() for n in nums if n != ''] # strip whitespace and get rid of empty lines

with open('D:\\Scripting Test\\Full Data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        for num in nums:
            if line.startswith(num):
                print(line)
```

Comment: @AhmedShouaib no problem